# Iterate through list passed by custom template tag

Tags: django, list, templates, tags

I have custom template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def random_num():
    numbers = range(1,18)
    shuffle(numbers)
    return numbers
```

In template:

```
{% for num in random_num  %}
    {{ num }}
{% endfor %}
```

gives nothing. `{% random_num %}` prints whole list nicely, but I need to iterate over all elements. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the templatetag as a variable, so:

```
{% for num in random_num  %}
```

can't work.

You need to change your templatetag to an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.assignment_tag)

```
@register.assignment_tag
def random_num():
    numbers = range(1,18)
    shuffle(numbers)
    return numbers
```

...and use the `as` clause in the template:

```
{% random_num as numlist %}
{% for num in numlist  %}
    {{ num }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [The `assignment_tag` has been deprecated and removed from Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0).

Answer (score 3):

Based on Anentropic's answer, in Django 2.0 you can continue to use the `simple_tag`, but you still have to use the `as` clause. The `assignment_tag` also, [has been deprecated and removed from Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0) .

Therefore, your tag can be:

```
@register.simple_tag
def random_num():
    numbers = range(1,18)
    shuffle(numbers)
    return numbers
```

And in the template you should use it as:

```
{% random_num as numlist %}
{% for num in numlist  %}
    {{ num }}
{% endfor %}
```